# Can reach my server with telnet but not with my client

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I am currently coding a small chat application in C for learning network.
I develop using the Transmission Control Protocol with socket in C. I was able to connect to my server with a client not coded by myself (on local network). Now telnet succeed to connect to my chat server(so with server and telnet client on the same computer) and I can send and receive message BUT my very simple client cannot connect to it.
Since the begining I use port 9002 and right now I am trying to connect with IPv6 address ::1. 
Here the "accept client" code of my server:

```
int main(void)
   {
    //Create the socket
    int sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    printf("Socket créer\n");

    //Set up the socket interface
    struct sockaddr_in6 sin6 = { 0 };
    sin6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    sin6.sin6_port = htons(PORT);
    sin6.sin6_addr = in6addr_any; 

    //Bind the socket on the port
    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sin6, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)) == SO_ERROR)
    {
        perror("bind()");
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Fail to bind");
    }

    //Make the sockey listen the port
    if(listen(sock, MAX_CLIENT) == SO_ERROR)
    {
        perror("listen()");
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Fail to listen");
    }

    printf("Socket listening\n");

    int csock;
    size_t clientID = 0;
    --snip--

    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in6 csin6;
        memset(&csin6, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
        int sin6size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);

        //Accept a communication
        printf("Wait for communication\n");
        csock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &csin6, &sin6size);
        printf("Connection accepted\n");
        char msg[16];
        sprintf(msg, "CONNECTED - %zu\n", clientID);
        send(csock, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
        printf("Client %zu connected\n", clientID);

        //Handle client
       --snip--
    }
```

So this is a basic connection with socket using connected communication. The server handle several client in the while loop thanks to threading.
Here the code of the client:

```
void *sender(void *arg)
{
    int socket = (int)(long)arg;
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s", buffer);
        send(socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        bzero(buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Usage: ./client <server ip>\n");

    //Create the socket
    int sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct hostent *hostinfo = NULL;
    hostinfo = gethostbyname2(argv[1], AF_INET6);
    if(hostinfo == NULL)
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Can't connect to the server\n");

    //Set up the socket interface
    struct sockaddr_in6 sin6 = { 0 };
    sin6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    sin6.sin6_port = htons(PORT);
    sin6.sin6_addr = *(struct in6_addr *)hostinfo->h_addr; 

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sin6, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == SO_ERROR)
    {
        perror("connect()");
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Fail to connect");
    }
    printf("Connection established\n");

    pthread_t sending;
    if(pthread_create(&sending, NULL, sender, (void *)(long)sock) != 0)
        printf("Fail to create a thread\n");

    //Handle reception
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
    int n;
    while((n = recv(sock, buffer, BUFF_SIZE - 1, 0)) >= 0)
    {
        buffer[n] = '\0';
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    printf("Erreur: %d\nConnection broken\n", n);
    pthread_cancel(sending);
    close(sock);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So I start the client with:

```
~ ./client ::1
```

The output is the following:

```
Connection established
Error: -1
Connection broken
```

While the server is still "Waiting for communication". This means that the server do not accept the connection but the client succeed to connect.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: try printing `errno` or `strerror(errno)` to see for what reason `recv()` fails

Comment: As I said in @Ctx answer, it fails before the `recv()` level, the `connect()` function fails first but as I specified `SO_ERROR` instead of simple `-1`, I was not able to see it

Comment: in general, the client does NOT 'bind()' to a port.  rather the server does that.  The client calls 'connect()' to create a connection between the client and the server.

Comment: When calling `socket()`, check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Fail to create a thread\n");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Also, when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output to `stderr`, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  An easy way to do all the above is to call `perror( "your error message" );`

Comment: regarding: `if(pthread_create(&sending, NULL, sender, (void *)(long)sock) != 0)
        printf("Fail to create a thread\n");`  The next statements should be cleaning up any allocated memory, open files, etc. then calling: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  The code should definitely not continue executing as if everything is alright.

Comment: Note: sockets are 'int' but should be typed as 'sock_t'  They are not 'long'

Comment: OT: when calling any C library function, like `send()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", buffer);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E. `if( scanf("%s", buffer) != 1) { //handle error and exit }`  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably already the `connect()`, which fails here:

```
if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sin6, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == SO_ERROR)
```

`SO_ERROR` is not meant to be used here, but as a socket option when retrieving the error when an asynchronous connect fails. A (synchronous) `connect()` returns -1 on error and sets `errno`, so do

```
if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sin6, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
```

...

Later, the recv here:

```
while((n = recv(sock, buffer, BUFF_SIZE - 1, 0)) >= 0)
```

fails with errno `ENOTCONN`, since the connection failed beforehand.

The same `SO_ERROR` mistake is present at various locations in your server code; it is possible, that already the `bind()` there fails! The call to `listen()` will then autobind it to a free ephemereal port, so the call as well as the call to `accept()` will succeed.

Why can the call to `bind()` fail? You might have to set the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` when (re-)starting the server, otherwise it might refuse to use a recently bound port if connections are still in `TIME_WAIT` state. Place this directly before the `bind()` call:

```
int one = 1;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one));
```

This might help.

Comment: You were right, the `connect()` function fails first. I replace my `SO_EROR` by `-1` everywhere and add the two lines before `bind()`. It fails with `connect() : Invalid argument` even with more than 5000 try in a loop.
But I am still not able to solve that problem.

Comment: I indeed overlooked that mistake. You have to use `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)`

Comment: I do not understand what it has to do but it does not work unfortunately.
Do you think that the problem can come from too much socket file desciptor open but not in use? When I kill the server with ^C, I don"t know it the socket are well closed, and I implement no command to close it properly.

Comment: Can you show your current code as a whole? Append it at the end of your question

Comment: Wich part do you want to see? The server or the client? The rest of the code is client handle with thread, supposing that the communcation is established correctly

Comment: The part, which throws the "Invalid Argument" error

Comment: The part that throws the error is `perrror("connect()");`
In the client code

Comment: Didn't I tell you to use `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)`?

Comment: It would be easier and safer to use `sizeof(sin6)` instead. And you should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead of `gethostbyname2()`. And the `recv()` loop needs to be stopped if `recv()` returns 0 on a graceful peer disconnect.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think you meant to add this to the question instead of my answer, correct?

Comment: @Ctx it was posted exactly where I intended it to be posted. The first sentence directly pertains to your earlier comment. The other sentences were added later

Comment: @RemyLebeau "it was posted"... _You_ posted it, and several of your sentences don't relate to this answer at all. Furthermore, it is neither "easier" nor "safer" to use `sizeof(sin6)`. You just claim some things without backing anything with arguments. Please consider posting your own, better answer - _with_ explanations - instead of pinging me with your pretentious comments.

Comment: @Ctx wow, you don't have to be an @$$ about it. There was nothing pretentious about my post, I was just making an observation, sheesh